# Mock up BlobBaseClient.DownloadTo

Tags: mocking, azure-blob-storage

What is the correct way to create a mock of BlobBaseClient.DownloadTo(Stream)?

So far, I have this and unfortunately the stream I'm trying to read from eventually doesn't contain anything

```
           var stream = new Mock<MemoryStream>();          
            var responseMock = new Mock<Response>();
            var xmlContent = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>test data</xml>";
            responseMock.Setup(r => r.Content).Returns(new BinaryData(xmlContent));
            responseMock.Setup(r => r.ContentStream).Returns(stream.Object);         
            _blobClientMock.Setup(b => b.DownloadTo(It.IsAny<MemoryStream>())).Returns(responseMock.Object);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To DownloadTo() here. You should not be reading a response stream from this API. The method writes response data for you to the stream provided in the arguments. A mock of this method should write mock response data to stream provided in the argument, not return mock data. E.g.

```html
byte[] xmlContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"<?xml version='1.0'?>test data</xml>");
var responseMock = new Mock<Response>();
// add some headers to the response if desired
_blobClientMock.Setup(c => c.DownloadTo(It.IsAny<Stream>()))
    .Callback((Stream s) => s.Write(xmlContent))
    .Returns(responseMock);
```

Please treat as pseudocode